# Conflicting ruby types on installations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've installed Ruby sucessfully in my machine. After I install rails, I do a `bundle install` command. I have some problems when installation reaches kgio. It complains to RubyDevKit installation.

```
Gem::InstallError: The 'kgio' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

An error occurred while installing kgio (2.10.0), and Bundler cannot 
continue.
Make sure that `gem install kgio -v '2.10.0'` succeeds before bundling.

After the installation I run `bundle update` and get conflicting types 
error.
```

This is the result of the mkmf.log file.

```
conftest.c:17:13: error: conflicting types for 'clock_gettime'
In file included from c:\rubydevkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-
mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/time.h:285:0,
             from c:\rubydevkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-
mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/iptypes.h:13,
             from c:\rubydevkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-
mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/iphlpapi.h:15,
             from C:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/win32.h:44,
             from C:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/defines.h:168,
             from C:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:36,
             from C:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33,
             from conftest.c:1:
```

I understood this is a conflicting types issue. The problem is when I install RubyDevKit and after that I do a `bundle update`.
If those things are interlaced and they produce those problems, how can I solve this?

My Ruby version: 2.3.1
RubyDevKit: mingw64-64-4.7.2
Rails: 4.6.2

Comment: Are you sure it would work on Windows platform? As I can see it: `run on Unix-like platforms`  https://rubygems.org/gems/kgio

Comment: Yes, with git cmd.

Comment: No, I meant are you sure that `kgio` can be compiled in Windows platform.

Comment: From the [KGIO homepage](https://bogomips.org/kgio/): "The library consists of a C extension so you'll need a *Unix-like system* with a C compiler and Ruby development libraries/headers." Looks like you need to work with a virtual environment.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Correct. Solution found is to develop on Ubuntu.